# Can Tastypie handle arbitrary arrays of objects?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm working on a project which requires REST API. I have tried Piston but it doesn't suit my requirement as it currently allows only 1 handler per model.

Tastypie seems to be a better alternative. However, I'm stuck with the following problem. My article class is displayed according to a complex rule such as ranking and date created. To enhance server performance, I created a dummy table which records the order of all the articles so that upon user requests, the complex ordering process will not be executed. Instead, the server checks for the orders of each article from the dummy table.

With Tastypie, a query set is required. However, because I want to use the orders recorded in the dummy table, I have to use a more complex code snippet to retrieve the data.

Is there any possibility that I can return an array of article objects and Tastypie can transform them into a proper JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is extending the `queryset` in `Meta`. Assuming your articles table should be ordered by some additional data your queryset would be defined for example like that:

```
Meta:
    queryset = Article.objects.extra(select={
       'ordering': 'SELECT foo FROM bar'
    },).order_by('ordering')
```

You have to define the additional fields in your resources:

```
ordering = field.IntegerField(attribute="ordering", default=0, readonly=True)
```

The additional field should now be returned with all other fields retrieved from your queryset. Note that if you define the `fields` attribute in your meta you also have to add the new field there.